# Couldn't install Axios in React Native via npm install axios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, npm, axios

I have done in React Js multiple times but it is my first time using axios in React Native. When I install axios through `npm install axios` it gives a huge log error related to other libraries .

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-location-view@0.3.0
npm ERR! Found: react-native-vector-icons@8.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-vector-icons
npm ERR!   peer react-native-vector-icons@">7.0.0" from react-native-elements@3.4.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-elements
npm ERR!     react-native-elements@"^3.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native-vector-icons@"*" from react-native-paper@4.9.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-paper
npm ERR!     react-native-paper@"^4.9.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-vector-icons@"^4.4.3" from react-native-location-view@0.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-location-view
npm ERR!   react-native-location-view@"^0.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native-vector-icons@4.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-vector-icons
npm ERR!   peer react-native-vector-icons@"^4.4.3" from react-native-location-view@0.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-location-view
npm ERR!     react-native-location-view@"^0.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Suyash\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Suyash\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-07T15_22_51_263Z-debug.log
```

It should have been same as React JS but for some reason these errors are appearing.

Comment: Although app is working fine with all these libraries .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an issue with Axios your dependencies are conflicting because they're out-dated. For example:

```
Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-vector-icons@"^4.4.3" from react-native-location-view@0.3.0
```

which is trying to pull version 4 and [React Native Vector Icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) is on version 9. You should update your dependencies and check for any conflicting code accordingly. Would also suggest using Yarn with React Native.

You can run in the terminal:

```
rm node_modules && rm package-lock.json && yarn install
```

if you have [Yarn installed](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/). If as you stated everything works correctly you could try:

```
npm i react-native-location-view --legacy-peer-deps
```

or:

```
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: Okk! I will try this. Let's hope it works. Thanks

Comment: Nahh, it didn't worked. I updated every lib but still the same.

Comment: @SuyashVashishtha made an edit with using `--legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: @DarthVader Thanks ! That worked.

Comment: Please mark it as the accepted answer.